# Need to insert /#/ into a url

Tags: nginx

I am trying to create a try_files or rewrite rule. Only for a particular url with a query

http://example.com/survey?id=5 becomes http://example.com/survey/#/?id=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
location =/server {
        rewrite ^ $scheme://example.com/server/# permanent;
}
```

- Using $scheme preserves the scheme of the request (http or https).
- Using location =/server matches requests to /server and you need the = to match only exact matches otherwise you'll keep getting redirected.

Comment: Thank you. I missed it was =/server once I fixed that it worked perfectly